# ltdl.h Not found error while building chaincode

Tags: go, blockchain, libtool, hyperledger-fabric, libltdl

I am trying to build a chaincode by using `go build`. when i run Go build command its reporting

```
.\hyperledger\fabric\vendor\github.com\miekg\pkcs11\pkcs11.g‌​o:29:18: 
fatal error:ltdl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

I  installed libtools from this [link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libtool.htm). But I am getting the same error

Comment: Make sure `ltdl.h` exist in `gcc`s include directory. Use `gcc -xc -E -v -` to list up the include directory.

Comment: i got this .. 

    "#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../include
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include-fixed
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.`

Comment: You have to download developer version of the libtools and put `ltdl.h` into one of the above directory.

Comment: can you share the link where to download developer version of libtools

Comment: Its at the link you've mentioned in the question. Its called develover files.

Answer (score 16):

It worked for me on ubuntu:
`sudo apt install libltdl-dev`

Answer (score 9):

if you are using centos/RHEL 7
you can use this code

```
yum install libtool-ltdl-devel
```

Answer (score 6):

For Mac, make sure you have brew installed. This command worked for me:

```
brew install libtool
```

Comment: Leaving a breadcrumb in case someone else runs into a `libltdl is required`, i.e for installing XmlSec on OSX. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

On Debian/Ubuntu environment, try using the following command:

sudo apt install libtool libltdl-dev

Comment: It seems only libtool is enough.                  #sudo apt install libtool

Answer (score 2):

make sure to add **--tags nopkcs11** to ur go build or go test command. The error should stop appearing

Example : go build --tags nopkcs11

This will compile your chaincode if you are in development and testing your code.