# Can't compile fabric on windows - missing ltdl.h

Tags: c++, hyperledger-fabric, libtool

I am trying to build a chaincode using `go build`.

Environment:

- installed go 1.8.3 windows/amd
- Windows 10

When I run `go build` I get the following error:

```
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11
..\..\github.com\hyperledger\fabric\vendor\github.com\miekg\pkcs11\pkcs11.go:29:18: fatal error: ltdl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I checked and my GCC installation does not contain the **ltdl.h** file in the *include* folder.

I found a SO post with a [solution for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626320/ltdl-h-not-found-error-while-building-chaincode), but not one for Windows.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows you can build without `PKCS`

`go build --tags nopkcs11`

Comment: Damn, I was hoping someone figured out how to get pkcs11 working on Windows. Will probably have to cross compile or use cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command

```
sudo apt install libtool libltdl-dev
```

Make sure `go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim` throws no error then `go build` it.